# How to compare two remote files using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Suppose there is file called `compare.txt` on remote host1 and host2.

I want to compare the two files if they are the same or not.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stat` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html) with `get_checksum` parameter set on (which anyway is a default setting).

Then compare the checksums.

Comment: can you please give any example how to use that? I can't see any example from the page.

Comment: It's not that unusual that a manual does not provide examples for all use cases someone can imagine. You need to write your code yourself. And you can always ask on StackOverflow if you encounter a problem.